# Which daemon realize afp fileshare in archlinux?

Tags: file-sharing, afp, arch-linux

How can I implement filesharing via apple´s afp protocol on an arch-linux box? My system should serve files to multiple clients with different operating systems. (Windows {XP,7},OS X) For the Windows part I installed Samba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are directions for setting up a [Linux AFP Server](http://www.kremalicious.com/2008/06/ubuntu-as-mac-file-server-and-time-machine-volume/)

But why not use Samba for both? Linux, Windows, and Mac all support CIFS (aka SMB, what Samba serves).

Comment: In my own testing, netatalk vastly outperformed CIFS/SMB for OS X clients, 3 to 5 times faster depending on the type of data. In particular, it was more performant for Time Machine backups.

Answer (score 0):

Also, look into using NFS. You may get greater performance and reliability with that.

I certainly don't like running it CIFS, unless i'm forced too.

I see you running a windows machine there, you'll have to use samba for this. Support for other
network file systems is flaky at best.

Answer (score 0):

The only program that I know of is [netatalk](http://netatalk.sf.net). But as others have mentioned, your OS X clients can mount smb shares as well.